# Java classnotfound error

Tags: java, web-services, noclassdeffounderror

I have a webservice client created using cxf. When I run from eclipse I dont get any errors. But when I create a jar out of the files and run it from cmd prompt , I get NoclassDef exception or ClassNot found exception. I have set the classpath, java home correct.

**1. Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
```

**2. Exception**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/databinding/DataBinding
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.databinding.DataBinding
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
```

The web service is in C# wcf and the client was created without JAXBinding element.
Anyhelp will be appreciated.

Thanks,
Priya.R

Comment: the ClassNotFound exception will have the name of the class as well. Can you please specify that as well.

Comment: Thanks Feroz. i have added that as well.

Comment: sounds like you are missing the jaxb jar. Which java version you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typically and easiy-to-solve classpath problem: The cxf library (-ies) is/are missing on the classpath. Start the application like this:

```
java -cp <youJar.jar>;<cxf.jar>[;<another-cxf.jar>;...] my.pkg.Application
```

You'll have to replace the name of the *main* class and the values of the `-cp` parameter with the paths and names of your jar and all other libraries that are required to run the application.

Why does it work from eclipse: In eclipse, you've set the *build path* correctly, but this builds path is not exported or added to the jar.